# Laravel 5.8: Getting Product Name Related To Order Detail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have this method at the Controller:

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request)
    {
        if(!empty($request->input('actions'))){
            if($request->input('actions')=='print_factors'){
                if(!empty($request->input('orderCheck'))) {
                    $args = [];
                    $orders = $request->input('orderCheck');
                    foreach ($orders as $ord){
                        $order = Order::find($ord);
                        $args[] = [
                            'order' => $order,
                            'address' => $order->order_address->first(),
                            'details' => $order->orderDetail,
                            'sendType' => $order->productSubmit,
                            'coupons' => $this->cartController->computeDiscountForOutRequests($order->ord_object_id, $order->ord_creator_id),
                            'user' => User::query()->find($order->ord_creator_id)
                        ];
                    }

                    return view('admin.shop.orders.printfactors', compact('args'));
                }else{
                    return back();
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Then at `printfactors.blade.php`, I have added this to get the `details` information which is actually connected to `orderDetail` Model:

```
@foreach($args as $arg)
    @forelse($arg['details'] as $detail)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{optional(($detail)->ort_reference_id)->prd_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
@endforeach
```

But I don't get the `prd_name` related to order. Meaning that it's empty. However, I have this product at `products` table:

[image]

And here `prd_id` is the foreign key connected with `ort_reference_id` of `order_detail` table:

**OrderDetail Model (`OrderDetail.php`):**

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'ort_reference_id', 'prd_id');
    }
```

And when I `dd($detail->ort_reference_id)` in `printfactors.blade.php`, I get **2** as the result, so it should be printing the `prd_name` related to this order, which is `Book` in this example.

So what's going wrong here, how can I show the product name in `printfactors.blade.php` based on each order properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can  call like this `optional($detail->product)->prd_name`

Full code

```
@foreach($args as $arg)
    @forelse($arg['details'] as $detail)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{optional($detail->product)->prd_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
@endforeach
```

or

```
  @foreach($args as $arg)
        @forelse($arg['details'] as $detail)
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{$detail->product->prd_name??null }}</td>
        </tr>
        @empty
        @endforelse
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all because you are not using the standard primary key for the table, so for product relation to work properly, you need to specify the primary id in the Product model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'prd_id';
```

By default, Laravel will assume the primary column name of the table either `id` or `product_id`

After that you can easily use the optional function to get the prd_name property if the record exists, otherwise it will return null.

```
optional($detail->product)->prd_name;
```

or you can use the ternary operator to check for the value

```
$detail->product ? $detail->product->prd_name : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get product name as-

```
optional($detail->product)->prd_name
```

As relational data available with the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call product on your order model like below:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">{{optional($detail->product)->prd_name?? '' }}</td>
```